# PHP redirect & url rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have tried already a couple of ways using URL redirect, but I am no good in php.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/Folder/([0-9]+)$ example.com/
```

I have a problem, the sub folders & files of my server are case-sensitive, for example:

```
www.example.com/Folder/index.html
```

1. How can I make them case insensitive, or redirect alternative spellings to:

   ```
   www.example.com/Folder/
   ```
2. I also want to hide the actual URL of all sub folders and files, e.g. only the below should be shown, not any sub-items.:

   ```
   www.example.com/Folder
   ```

I have no CMS, only static HTML pages.

Comment: Are you using Apache?

Comment: I think case-sensitivity doesn't play any role here.

Comment: What exactly do you want to do, I understand you don't want to show sub folders but what you want? By default that directory should open the `index.html` so nothing else would be displayed. What does PHP have to do with this if you're talking about HTML pages and shows nothing of what you've tried with PHP? Your question is very unclear as it is.

Comment: This does not concern PHP one bit. It's all about server-side URL routing...PHP only comes in play when/if you need particular and flexible routing logic.

Comment: the question is directed towards htaccess to hide sub-folders. For example: there are 5 different html pages in /Folder, which can be accessed through the main index.html page, but show page2.html when openend. But I don't want to show that, only alway example.com/Folder and no example.com/Folder/page.html. Clearer now?

Comment: Clearer and not possible as it is on your idea/explanations as it would not know to what page it should go, however you could do something like: `example.com/Folder`, `example.com/Folder/1`, `example.com/Folder/2`, etc without creating new folders to represent pages and internally redirect it to the `page.html` in question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `mod_speling` to allow case-insensitive URLs. It is bundled with the default installation of Apache; you just have to enable it in `.htaccess`:

```
CheckSpelling On
```

To hide files, turn directory listings off:

```
Options -Indexes
```

Comment: mh.. I tried it, but that just made all pages inaccessable. ( even only CheckSpelling ON )

Comment: here's what I tried: RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/Folder/([0-9]+)$ example.com/